# промежуточные итоги

Tags: sql-server, datetime, group-by

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Добрый день! В результате SQL запроса  необходимо вывести значения за последние 3 дня с промежуточными итогами (с помощью оператора ROLLUP) за весь предыдущий год. Каким образом это сделать в 1 запросе? с помощью подзапроса?

```
DECLARE @bdt DATETIME = Cast('24.05.2017 00:00:00' AS DATETIME)
            DECLARE @edt DATETIME = Cast('27.05.2017 23:59:00' AS DATETIME)
DECLARE @adt DATETIME = EOMONTH( dateadd(yy,-1,@bdt),-1)
select *
from(
            select
    iif(Grouping(dt) = 1, 73049, dt) AS dt
                  ,sum(t1.[a]) as [a]
                  ,sum(t1.[b]) as [b]
                  ,sum(t1.[v]) as [v]
              from(select [a]
                         ,[b]
                         ,[v]
                        ,dt
                  from tab
              where dt between @adt and @edt
)t1
where dt between @adt and Dateadd(dd,365,@adt)
     group by rollup(dt)
```

Comment: Дополните ваш вопрос своим запросом

Comment: дополнил запросом

Comment: Как то не понятно звучит вопрос. Вам нужна сумма за 3 дня и ежедневные итоги за год. Или один итог за год, плюс итоги за каждый из 3 дней. Лучше приведите в вопросе пример вывода данных, так что бы было видно за какой период в каком разрезе должны быть итоги. И у вас gorup by сейчас дает правильный результат, а то ведь если дата хранится с временем, то group by dt сгруппирует с точностью до миллисекунд, т.е. фактически ничего не сгруппирует

Comment: мне нужны почасовые значения в таблице за последние 3 дня и промежуточный итог за прошедший год последней строкой. В результате вышеуказанного запроса получаются почасовые результаты за весь год, а не за последние 3 дня как необходимо-запрос недописан

Comment: Думаю год будет проще собрать отдельно и присоединить к запросу с помощью union. И никаких rollup не нужно. Потому что у вас итоги не промежуточные. За один проход таблицы в принципе можно, но будет более громоздко, а выигрыш по скорости из за 3х дней будет мизерный и скорее всего незаметный (если вообще не отрицательный из за более сложных расчетов)

Comment: т.е. буквально `select [a]
                         ,[b]
                         ,[v]
                        ,dt
                  from tab
              where dt between @bdt and @edt group by до-часа UNION ALL select sum(),sum(),.... where dt between @adt and Dateadd(dd,365,@adt)`

Comment: Еще у вас очень странные даты. там получается 3 дня за пределами выбранного года.  если бы это было не так, что where можно было бы сделать `between @adt and Dateadd(dd,365,@adt)` и написать что то вроде `group by rollup(case when dt between @bdt and @edt
         then dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, dt), 0)
         else @adt end)`

Comment: сделал через UNION ALL но руководитель говорит что можно и нужно сделать через 1 запрос...

Comment: тогда с датами объясните что происходит. У вас те 3 дня в год похоже не входят. должны ли они суммироваться в него то же ? У меня сложилось ощущение, что вам нужны 365 дней, оканчивающиеся в последнее число предыдущего (к этим 3 дням) месяца. А тогда по логике эти 3 дня суммироваться с ним не должны. Или можете показать union который вас устроил по результату, по нему будет яснее что требуется. P.S. У меня ощущение, что вам будет достаточно того case, который я внутри rollup написал

Comment: С текущими датами, если не писать OR на два диапазона дат в where (его вам может и разрешат, но это хуже чем union) у нас на выходе получаются 3 диапазона: предыдущий год, N-е кол-во дней между тем годом и 3 днями и наконец 3 дня. И вот те N дней надо получается не учитывать ни в одном итоге. тогда на них нужен отдельный блок в case, который их приведет например к дате NULL и потом эту дату в having выбрасывать

Comment: а почему OR хуже чем UNION? если писать через OR с CASE то результат верный если так     where dt between adt and Dateadd(dd,365,dt) OR dt between bdt and edt
     group by rollup(dt)

Comment: Ну вы посмотрите что вам на этот OR оптимизатор скажет. В принципе может два скана по индексу все таки нарисует, раз OR всего один. Но оптимизатор в принципе OR не любит и грозит свалится на full scan, хотя когда год отбираете, может это и не плохо. И я не понял, как rollup(dt) мог дать верный результат, он же год так же по часу распишет

Comment: DECLARE bdt DATETIME = Cast('13.12.2017 00:00:00' AS DATETIME)
                DECLARE edt DATETIME = Cast('29.12.2017 23:59:59' AS DATETIME)
    DECLARE adt DATETIME = EOMONTH( dateadd(yy,-1,bdt),-1)


   select * from(
                   select
        case when dt between bdt and edt then dt else
        case
       when Grouping(dt) = 1 then 73049 end end as dt

Comment: where dt between adt and Dateadd(dd,365,adt) OR dt between bdt and edt
     group by rollup(dt)
                ) t3
    where dt is not null

Comment: вот такие у меня условия и отбор получились но тут что то неправильно

Comment: мне почему то кажется, что rollup все таки не нужен. И что бы группировка года была одной строкой, то в group by надо указать такой же case как у вас выборке. Он как раз соберет год одной записью, а остальное с детализацией по dt

Comment: а можете написать как это должно приблизительно выглядеть?